# Realm <Results> Loses Data Outside Function

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am still new to coding and I am experiencing some issues with Realm Cloud that no matter how hard I try I cannot seem to fix. I am trying to create a sample of a 'Click & Collect' order tracker, which when the `orderState` object property is changed between 1-4 (numbers represent different stages) it changes the UI to the corresponding screen. I have subscribed to a Realm observation of the `Results<Order>`object, in the function where the observation and notifications take place `currentOrder` contains the correct `Order`object. However I have a switch for the `changes` from the observation which calls a function to update to the correct UI. Inside this called function `currentOrder` suddenly contains no data, `currentOrder` was defined on a global scope so I can't understand why this is happening. I filter the `Results<Order>` to only query the matching ID (observations do not seem to be working for me at all when matching by primary key and bypassing the `Results`).

I am going to add the entirety of the VC here, the only important note is that the `currentOrderID` property is passed over from the previous VC where the object was written to Realm. If you scroll down until `func prepareRealm` & `func changeUIBasedOnStatus` this is where the problems lie and I have also included the console message at the end inc. print statement results.

```
//
//  TrackerViewController.swift
//  HG Demo
//
//  Created by Adam Woodcock on 12/03/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Adam Woodcock. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Lottie
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class TrackerViewController: UIViewController {
    //Lottie Views
    @IBOutlet weak var orderPlacedAnimation: LOTAnimationView!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderConfirmedAnimation: LOTAnimationView!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderPickedAnimation: LOTAnimationView!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderCompleteAnimation: LOTAnimationView!

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressImage: UIImageView!


    let config = SyncUser.current?.configuration()
    var realm : Realm!

    var currentOrder : Results<Order>!
    var currentOrderID : String!
    var subscription : SyncSubscription<Order>!
    var subscriptionToken : NotificationToken?
    var notificationToken : NotificationToken?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        realm = try! Realm(configuration: config!)
        currentOrder = realm.objects(Order.self).filter("orderID = %@", currentOrderID!)
        prepareRealm()
        startOrderPlacedAnimation()

    }

    //Lottie functions
    func startOrderPlacedAnimation() {
        orderPlacedAnimation.setAnimation(named: "orderPlaced")
        orderPlacedAnimation.play()
        orderPlacedAnimation.loopAnimation = true
        orderConfirmedAnimation.isHidden = true
        orderCompleteAnimation.isHidden = true
        headingLabel.text = "Thank you! Your order has been placed!"
        bodyLabel.text = "Your order has been successfully placed, we'll notify you once this has been accepted!"
        progressImage.image = UIImage(named: "singleCheck")
    }

    func startOrderConfirmedAnimation() {
        orderConfirmedAnimation.isHidden = false
        orderConfirmedAnimation.setAnimation(named: "undedited")
        orderConfirmedAnimation.play()
        orderConfirmedAnimation.loopAnimation = true
        orderPlacedAnimation.isHidden = true
        orderCompleteAnimation.isHidden = true
        headingLabel.text = "It's Official! Your order is confirmed!"
        bodyLabel.text = "A team member has confirmed your order, we'll start packing soon!"
        progressImage.image = UIImage(named: "doubleCheck")
    }

    func startOrderPickedAnimation() {
        orderPickedAnimation.isHidden = false
        orderPickedAnimation.setAnimation(named: "orderPicked")
        orderPickedAnimation.play()
        orderPickedAnimation.loopAnimation = true
        orderPlacedAnimation.isHidden = true
        orderConfirmedAnimation.isHidden = true
        orderCompleteAnimation.isHidden = true
        headingLabel.text = "Woosh! Your order is being packed!"
        bodyLabel.text = "A team member with extremely steady hands is currently packing your order!"
        progressImage.image = UIImage(named: "tripleCheck")

    }

    func startOrderCompleteAnimation() {
        orderCompleteAnimation.isHidden = false
        orderCompleteAnimation.setAnimation(named: "orderComplete")
        orderCompleteAnimation.play()
        orderCompleteAnimation.loopAnimation = true
        orderPlacedAnimation.isHidden = true
        orderConfirmedAnimation.isHidden = true
        orderPickedAnimation.isHidden = true
        headingLabel.text = "Woohoo! Your order is ready to collect!"
        bodyLabel.text = "We're as excited as you, so what're you waiting for? Come and grab it!"
        progressImage.image = UIImage(named: "quadrupleCheck")
    }

    func startOrderHasBeenCollectedAnimation() {

    }

    func startErrorWithOrderAnimation() {

    }

    //Realm functions

    //Assigning the current order to the Order object variable
    func prepareRealm() {
        subscription = currentOrder.subscribe(named: "current-order", limit: nil)
        subscriptionToken = subscription.observe(\.state, options: .initial, { (state) in })
        notificationToken = currentOrder.observe({ (changes) in
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                self.changeUIBasedOnStatus(sender: "Initial")
            case .update :
                self.changeUIBasedOnStatus(sender: "Update")
            case .error(let error):
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        print("Realm prepared, this is the object: \(currentOrder!)")
        titleLabel.text = "\(String(currentOrder.first!.firstName))'s Order #\(currentOrder.first!.orderID!)"
    }

    func changeUIBasedOnStatus(sender: String) {
        print("The switch realm object contains: \(currentOrder!), sender: \(sender)")
        switch currentOrder.first!.orderStatus {
        case 1:
            startOrderPlacedAnimation()
        case 2:
            startOrderConfirmedAnimation()
        case 3:
            startOrderPickedAnimation()
        case 4:
            startOrderCompleteAnimation()
        case 5:
            startOrderHasBeenCollectedAnimation()
        default:
            startErrorWithOrderAnimation()
        }
    }

    //IBActions
    @IBAction func callUsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let number = URL(string: "tel://+441522684865") else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.open(number, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func openingHoursTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func directionsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //Creating an action sheet to ask the user whether they'd like to use Apple Maps or Google Maps
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        //Adding the action and functionality to load Apple maps
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Maps", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            //Creating a placemark object to pass into the map item
            let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.203498, -0.611785))
            //Initialising a new map item object with the pre-made placemark object
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
            mapItem.phoneNumber = "+44 (0) 1522 684865"
            //Setting the launch options to default to driving directions
            let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
            //Telling the map item object to open that specific location in maps
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            //Add Google maps functionality
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The console message:

```
2019-03-14 17:00:52.132718+0000 HG Demo[51949:3038807] Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '3.121.59.66:443' (from '192.168.0.21:64953')
Realm prepared, this is the object: Results<Order> <0x7fdce8c2d370> (
    [0] Order {
        firstName = Adam;
        lastName = Woodcock;
        orderID = 4431295;
        timestamp = 2019-03-14 17:00:54 +0000;
        orderStatus = 1;
        isFulfilled = 0;
    }
)
The switch realm object contains: Results<Order> <0x7fdce8c2d370> (

), sender: Initial
(lldb)
```

The fatal error is on the switch statement in `changeUIBased...` specifically the `switch currentOrder.first!.orderStatus` is where it throws the 'Unexpectedly found nil...' error.

I know this is a little long winded so thank you in advance for any help.

[EDIT]

For clarification purposes I have removed all of the code to do with the Realm notifications from the `prepareRealm` function, I assign the `currentOrder[0]` to a variable called `thisOrder` to make this of type `Object` and not of type `Results`. I then print the value of `thisOrder` to which the order correctly prints the values. Alas I then print `thisOrder` inside a timer closure and it now prints as [invalid object]. The timer is symbolic in the sense that whenever the values `currentOrder` or `thisOrder` are passed outside of the `prepareRealm` function or to a closure the object becomes invalid. I have done this multiple times in different apps and even in this app on a seperate VC and it works 100% smoothly so I really can't understand why this is happening.

```
func prepareRealm() {
    realm = try! Realm(configuration: config!)
    currentOrder = realm.objects(Order.self).filter("orderID = %@", currentOrderID)
    thisOrder = currentOrder[0]
    print("This is thisOrder: \(thisOrder!)")

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        print(self.thisOrder)
    }

}
```

[EDIT 2]
I updated Realm to the newest version and everything started working! I thought this was the cause of the problem, however I have since carried on building different elements and testing etc. and all of a suddden it has started doing this again each and every time, I feel this could be an issue with Realm so will submit a bug with them.

Comment: `currentOrder = realm.objects(Order.self).filter("orderID = %@", currentOrderID!)` may result in currentOrder being nil because currentOrderID isn't populated when that line is called. I know you addressed that but it's being force-unwrapped so what if it was nil? Additionally, you're being pretty mean to your code; force-unwrapping options is dangerous - they are optionals for a reason and could be nil (which is why they are optionals). Treat them nicely and protect your code. Handle cases where they are nil (like this case) with error trapping and/or default values.

Comment: Can't actually see any problem yet; as you say, the `currentOrder` results collection is empty when you call it. Couple of suggestions in lieu of the actual error: (1) instead of using a results collection to refer to one order, just maintain a reference to the order (i.e. change `currentOrder` to be of type `Order`), (2) are you sure the id doesn't change at all somewhere?

Comment: @Jay thank you for coming back to me I appreciate the help. This is not the case as I simply used an '!' when defining this property to initialise it as the value is passed in from the previous VC. If the value fails to pass over an error is thrown from the previous VC. I should probably change this to a computed property to avoid the unnecessary '!'.

Comment: @ChrisShaw thank you also for trying to help, I wanted to do this originally, it makes so much more sense but I can't seem to add notifications to a single Object in Realm Cloud, I have done so in Realm Database but the same methods are not available here. If you both have time I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at my edit to the original post and see if this gives you any more clues.

Comment: There's a bit too much unrelated code there so you should probably consider reducing the code; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There may be a slight misunderstanding in the code; it seems you're treating the results returned from realm as a single object with `currentOrder = realm.objects(Order.self).filter("orderID = %@", currentOrderID!)`. While the function is filtered so you may think it's returning a single object, it's still a Results object that could be 1, 10 or 1000 objects. If you know for a fact it's a single object, the `var currentOrder = results.first` will do it. However, a much better approach is to just get that one object `currentOrder = realm.object(ofType: Order.self, forPrimaryKey: "order_id")`.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the heads up I'll cut the extra next time. In terms of this I have tried `.first` `[0]` etc. and I got the same results, I think this just happened to be the iteration I was attempting at the time of writing. As Realm support have given me an answer below I will try their suggestions and then feedback. Thank you for taking the time to give me advice and guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that there's a bunch of things happening in the background that may happen in inconsistent orders, since it involves talking to the server. One possible sequence of events which would cause problems is:

1. Create `Order` object locally
2. Write transaction is uploaded to server
3. View controller queries for the object and finds it.
4. View controller creates the subscription locally.
5. View controller logs message indicating the object exists.
6. Server processes the write transaction which created the object. The newly created object doesn't match any of the subscriptions the server knows about, so it tells the client to remove the newly added object.
7. Client invalidates the observed object.
8. Server processes the new subscription and tells the client to restore the object
9. Client restores the object, but that doesn't restore the invalidated reference to it or the observer.

If these happen in a slightly different order (e.g. the server happens to process the object creation and subscription creation at the same time), everything will work.

There's a few options to fix this:

1. Just observe the `Results<Order>` and handle the case when `.first` is `nil` temporarily
2. Create the subscription for the object before creating the object, so that it doesn't get temporarily removed from the client.
3. In the view controller observe the subscription and wait for it to reach the `.complete` state before setting up the object observer.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas, I really appreciate you coming back to me so quickly considering I only submit the request on Friday afternoon - Realm certainly does thinks well including their support quite clearly. I hadn't really thought about the time between the write transaction and the subscription. As you saw the write transaction happens immediately before the segue from the previous VC and the subscriptions/observations happen in `viewDidLoad`. I had to stop trying to fix this as it was driving me mad but I'll give these suggestions a go tomorrow and feedback to you then. Take care!

Comment: I couldn't resist having a look last night, I tried option 3 first and everything works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Order` must have all the properties marked with `dynamic` modifier for Realm to be able to override the getter/setter.

So your Order will look something like this:

```
class Order: Object {
    @objc dynamic var firstName = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastName = ""
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me, all of the properties in the `Order` model are marked as dynamic and done correctly, I have a separate VC displaying all of the orders in a Table View and using the same observation methods and this VC works perfectly with no issues